# Css select child elements from parent div

Tags: css

I have this html:

```html
<div class="banner-right">
  <img src="images/circle-icon.png" alt="">
  <p class="rotate mt-40">和小物</p>
  <p class="rotate mta">和小物</p>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select the first and last `p` element so that I can increase it's font size to `20px` and `15px`

**My scss code:**

```css
.banner-right {
  width: 122px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  img {
    width: 25px;
  }
  .swiper-pagination {
    position: relative;
  }
  .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    &.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
      background-color: #000;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }
  &:first-of-type {
    p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  }
  &:last-of-type {
    p {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

But doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, your Sass will compile to:

```
.banner-right:first-of-type p
```

But you want it to be:

```
.banner-right p:first-of-type
```

So change your Sass as follows:

```
.banner-right {
  p:first-of-type {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  p:last-of-type {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: shall I need to use `&` for the css pseudo element in Sass?

Comment: the `&` is for directly applying the class it is in front of to the class that is it's parent without any space - eg for your pagination you could do: `.swiper-pagination { &-bullet {} }`.  As these pseudo classes are not directly applied to the parent but are applied to the p as a child in the parent, you do not need the ampersand

Comment: I understand, Thank You.